# Getting the same error only occasionally using message.channel.awaitMessages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been making a Discord bot that has a quiz command. Everything works great but sometimes my embed that confirms the correct answer doesn't go through, and I end up with this error:

```
(node:23220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Collection>
(node:23220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23220) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am new to promises and I don't know why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
 const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

      message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                let ans = collected.first()

                console.log(ans)

                if (ans.content.toLowerCase() === correctAnswer.toLowerCase()) {
                    message.channel.send({ embed: { title: ":white_check_mark: You got the question right!", color: colours.green } })
                } else {
                    message.channel.send({ embed: { title: ":x: You got the question wrong! Correct answer: " + correctAnswer, color: colours.red } })
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is a warning that you have a `.then()`, but no `.catch()` and an error happened that your code didn't catch successfully.

If you check out [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) there is an example that does the following:

```js
// Await !vote messages
const filter = m => m.content.startsWith('!vote');
// Errors: ['time'] treats ending because of the time limit as an error
channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 4, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
  .then(collected => console.log(collected.size))
  .catch(collected => console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 voted.`));
```

It mentions that `errors: ['time']` will return a timeout error. You could either

1. remove that `errors: ['time']`
2. handle the error with a `.catch()` (which is the better solution, there might be other errors)

Comment: So if i put a catch, whatever code i enter in there will be executed when there is an error?

Comment: Yup. From their docs they always give you a `collected` argument in the `catch()` handler, but it might be empty.